# diff_drive_controller in ROS2 on Jackal platform causing jittered controls

Tags: ros2, clearpath, jackal, diff-drive-controller

I am currently battling with the ClearPath Jackal robot trying to upgrade it. I have struggled for weeks trying to understand why using a PS4 controller gives jittery values. Basically the jackal will randomly start and stop when I have the controller joystick full forward. It also will randomly start and stop turning when fully left or right on the joystick. I have now discovered that the controller is not the issue. I have been able to ros2 topic echo and see that at axis values 1.0 0, -1.0 0, 0 1.0, 0 -1.0, the cmd_vel is output as 0. I have calibrated the PS4 controller multiple times and the same thing happens. I am just unsure of where the input from the PS4 controller goes and how the axis is calculated to motor speeds. Because whatever is calculating it, is getting it wrong when the joystick is full forward, backward, left, or right. Is there a way to just give it certain values when the stick is in any of these positions?

Answer (score 0):

Please reach out to Clearpath support for assistance with these new packages support@clearpathrobotics.com.

Note: I am a Clearpath software developer. In my eyes this is the appropriate solution because we can assist through the support team to directly address the issue in the full context and fix any issues in the packages (if present). If anyone else is having this same issue and comes across this answer here then they should also contact Clearpath support.

Comment: No problem :-)...